# Linq Master Details, Details only Return 1 row

Tags: c#, linq

I have linq code like this

```cs
var tb1 = (
    from a in db.DSCom_t_summary_performance_sales
    where a.SALES_CODE == User.Identity.Name
    select new
    {
        a.INGESTION_DATE,
        a.SALES_CODE,
        a.STATUS,
        a.POSITION,
        a.DIVISION,
        a.DEPARTMENT,
        a.JML_SO,
        a.JML_NAB,
        a.JML_REVENUE,
        a.JML_ACCOUNT_PAID,
        details = (from d in db.DSCom_t_data_detail_performance_sls_sally
                    where d.SLSREP == a.SALES_CODE
                    select d).ToList()
    });

List<object> ret = new List<object>();
ret.Add(tb1);
return ret.AsQueryable();
```

what I want to achive here is master details from two table to API return JSON, but my code only return 1 row on details, is there any work around ?

Comment: You have added `IQuerybale` Into `ret` list. It has no sense of me.

Comment: Use a navigation property (`a.Details`). BTW, what is `db`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a join.  It can also be done with a SelectMany()

```
var tb1 = (from a in db.DSCom_t_summary_performance_sales.Where(x => x.SALES_CODE == User.Identity.Name)
           join d in db.DSCom_t_data_detail_performance_sls_sally on d.SLSREP == a.SALES_CODE
           select new { 
                         a.INGESTION_DATE,
                         a.SALES_CODE,
                         a.STATUS,
                         a.POSITION,
                         a.DIVISION,
                         a.DEPARTMENT,
                         a.JML_SO,
                         a.JML_NAB,
                         a.JML_REVENUE,
                         a.JML_ACCOUNT_PAID,
                         d
           }).ToList()
```